# Regex or `nil` in validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I'm writing this validation in Rails:

```
PRICE_GROUPS.each do |field_number|
  fix_price.validates_format_of :"child_price_group_#{field_number}",
                                :with => /\A\d+\.?\d{0,2}\z/,
                                message: 'Must not be more than 2 decimal places'
end
```

How do I change this to also allow the current regex or `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by doing this:

```
PRICE_GROUPS.each do |field_number|      
  fix_price.validates_format_of       :"child_price_group_#{field_number}",
                                      :with => /\A\d+\.?\d{0,2}\z/,
                                      message: 'Must not be more than 2 decimal places',
                                      allow_blank: true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `|`:

```
/\A(?:\d+\.?\d{0,2}|)\z/
```

or

```
/\A(?:\d+\.?\d{0,2})?\z/
```